# SyntaxError when quickstart for Python3/uWSGI

Tags: django, python-3.x, ubuntu-14.04, uwsgi

I wasted many time but couldn't find a solution. Ask for help.
I use ubuntu server 14.04, setup uwsgi by:

```
pip3 install uwsgi
```

Then I create the test.py:

```
def application(env, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
    return [b"Hello World"]
```

After I run:

```
uwsgi --http :8001 --wsgi-file test.py
```

It shows:

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.12 (64bit) on [Sat Mar 26 13:06:41 2016] ***
compiled with version: 4.8.4 on 26 March 2016 09:06:13
os: Linux-3.13.0-65-generic #106-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 2 22:08:27 UTC 2015
nodename: iZ282na6z2kZ
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /home
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 15834
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 65535
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uWSGI http bound on :8001 fd 4
spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 24498)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:57629 (port auto-assigned) fd 3
Python version: 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:31:36)  [GCC 4.8.4]
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x16fa3b0
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 72760 bytes (71 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
  File "test.py", line 3
    return [b'Hello World']
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
failed to parse file test.py
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 24497, cores: 1)
```

Why there is a syntax error for python3?

P.S sorry for my English   :P

Comment: Are you sure you posted your _actual_ code and not simplified it for asking here? I can't see a syntax error with this one.

Comment: Yes, it's the actual code, that's why really confused me.  I follow the uWSGI document step by step. Using pip3 to install uwsgi,  did it wrong? :(

Comment: @Selcuk notice the error says _line 3_ so that function is the very first thing in the file and that is what raises the syntax error.

Comment: @JoshuaHoo, did you figure it out?  Are you able to run the code with the normal python interpreter?  Is it possible there were non-printing characters in the file?